# Zelle accidentally sent me a “transaction credit”

Tags: credit, transaction

The amount is the same that is deposited into my account for my full time job so I contacted my employers already as well. Now sure if Zelle can take the money back?

Comment: Who told you that Zelle sent you this credit?  Did the information come from Zelle or your bank?  The most likely possibility is that your bank's web site or phone app has a bug that displayed the dollar amount from the wrong transaction.

Comment: Is your full time job a legitimate, real employer with an office you visit everyday and staff you interact with personally?  Because this also sounds like the lead-in to an [overpayment scam](https://www.doj.nh.gov/consumer/dont-cash-that-check/check-overpayment.htm), where they go "whoops, can you send that money back to us via Western Union, Bitcoin or Apple gift cards" ...  and then they reverse the payment...  (Zelle isn't reversible *for you*, but if the sender's account was hacked, it is...)

Comment: What kind of employer is that, to send your paycheck via Zelle? Sounds _very_ much like scam.